# Visio - Error : The unattended Service Account Application ID is not specified or has an invalid value

Tags: 2013, error, visio-services

My fresh SP 2013 farm install is working very well. I still have only one warning, and I would like to get rid of it.

The warning is about VisioGraphicsService :

```
The unattended Service Account Application ID is not specified or has an invalid value.
```

I googled that, and it seems that I have to create an application in the SecureStoreService.

So I went through the SecureStoreService, and it told me that I have to create a key. I did so.
Now it's telling me that SecureStoreService does not contain any target application.

So in order to get rid of this error, is that the right way ? Create a new target application where I choose the name I want and the ID.

What can I fill in the email contact field ? and in application type ?
I did read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806866(v=office.15).aspx#CreateTargetApp), but it didn't help me understand how does all this work.

Once I created the target application, I just report the ID I created on the Visio Service application, and then, no error ?

TIA

P.S : Maybe I should not care about this warning ? and let him alone ? Because no one in company use Visio in SharePoint right now ... But maybe if I can make it works, ppl will use it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Create a Secure Store Service
- Generate a new key
- Create a Target Application specific to Visio
- Copy the Target Application ID
- Paste it in the Visio Graphics Service Global Settings

Source: http://daniecsp.blogspot.com/2012/11/sp-2010-unattended-service-account.html

Comment: I just follow, without brain, and it works. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything else using the Secure Terms Store?

If you don't then the easiest solution is to remove both the Secure Store Service and Visio Services Application then recreate the Secure Store and set it up with a key. once you've done that successfully, recreate the Visio Services and input your unattended service account credentials.

Comment: I've just created the key in the SecureStoreService. To be honest, I don't really know what "unattended service account" I have to use. Do I really need to remove SecureStoreService and Visio Service Application ? I'm afraid this will cause warnings and errors :(
As my key is new, can't I just remove Visio Application and recreate it ?

Comment: The unattended service account is one of the service accounts you should have created in AD when you installed sharepoint along with your install account, farm account and the accounts you're using for search and service app pools.